# How to cache individual resources when returning a collection of that resource?

Tags: rest, caching

I'm sure that this must be either a well solved problem, or there's a good reason why it's not a good idea, but my google-fu is failing me here.

Say I have an express endpoint like this:

```
const allUsers = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "Alice Smith"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "Bob Smith"
    }
]; 

app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=60"); 
    res.status(200).send(allUsers)
});
```

This works fine, when my browser attempts the refetch the `/users` endpoint within the 60 seconds, it just uses the browser cache.

The problem is, say I have an endpoint for an individual user:

```
app.get("/users/:id", (req, res) => {

    const id = req.params.id; 
    const user = allUsers.find((v) => v.id === id); 
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=60"); 
    res.status(200).send(user)
});
```

Sure, this will similarly cache results for subsequent calls that particular endpoint.

However, what I really want to do is have the server tell the browser, when the browser does that first fetch of `/users` to, 'Hey, also cache `/users/1` and `/users/2`, destructure the response body to work out the values'.

Is this in anyway possible, or has such a mechanism ever been proposed?

Is there any mechanism within a browser, to programmatically set endpoint caches, without actually calling the endpoint?

Comment: Closest thing I know of is "server push", where the server returns representations of multiple resources to a single request ("you asked for /users, so here is /users and also /users/1 and /users/2 which you are likely to want soon")

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason have you got a link to what you're referring to?

Comment: https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#PushResources

Comment: It's not something I use, so I can't offer links to useful tutorials, or anything like that.  A quick google search did also turn up https://evertpot.com/http-2-push-is-dead/  which maybe isn't promising....